# How to setup eclipse to work with code sourcery toolchain for arm

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, gcc

I haven't worked with stm32f4 on linux for a while.
And it seems that a lot of changed since the last time I installed the toolchain.

First of all, after I've installed GNU ARM Eclipse plugin I realized that there is support for C++ there. Am I right? Have they created some HAL over the stm32 pheripherial libraries in C++?

Second. I've installed code courcery lite compiler. And I've chosen the right tool chain in eclipse project settings. But It gives me this error.

```
arm-none-eabi-g++: error: nano.specs: No such file or directory
```

I can see that in the linker scripts there is mysterious (to me) line

```
specs=nano.specs
```

So I've read about the specs flag. It seems that in this specs there should be some constant flags or settings for the compiler. But why are they not where the compiler whants them? And from where they should come?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm very new to the Gnu-Arm-Eclipse-Plugin myself and faced the same Problem.
I'm running Kubuntu1404 and have the gcc-arm-none-eabi toolchain installed.

Here is what I found out:

The GNU ARM Eclipse plugin links against the newlib-nano by default and if this library is not present in your toolchain you will get this error.

This is done through the linker flag  --specs=nano.specs which you can change through Project->Properties->C/C++ Build->Settings->Tool Settings->Cross ARM C++ Linker(Miscellaneous) .

*.specs files add additional instructions to the linker and so does nano.specs .
It should be located in $TOOLCHAINPATH/arm-none-eabi/lib/

As far as I know the newlib-nano and so the nano.specs file have been removed from recent gcc toolchains. At least it is not in the *buntu build of gcc-arm 4.8.3 .

There is a discussion ongoing on launchpad to include it again in future builds.

A workarround for me has been to use another toolchain like gcc-arm-none-eabi-4.7.3.

Edit: You can download a tarball from http://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded/+download but if you run a 64-bit OS you need a few 32-bit libraries.

On *buntu a 
    sudo apt get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0
will do th job.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for your answer. I've already figured it out and just removed --specs=nano... from linker flags.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I am using Xubuntu 14.04 64 bit and the very last line of your comment helped me out!